# Programmatically auto-fill UAC details

Tags: c#, uac

Is there a way to, via programmatically, auto-fill in the UAC login name and password in Visa?

For instance, the UAC prompt comes up.
Your program auto-fills that information for you.

E.g., a program that would auto-fill that information with an administrator username and password in the UAC prompt.

SendKeys does not work to send input keys to the UAC dialog box

Comment: Good question, but I can imagine this is an absolute no-no for Window's UI guidelines.

Comment: Good question needs a good answer :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There's probably a better way but it depends exactly what you are aiming to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several levels of UAC. I believe what you want is not possible if you use the UAC with the "greyed" screen. This mode is there to specifically **not** allow other programs access to the UAC-Window.

Comment: It is the grayed screen UAC :(

Answer (score 1):

If yu're logged into the machine as an administrator, you don't need to provide an ID and password, just click Consent. If you have the good habit of not signing on as an administrator, you can relax that habit now because UAC prevents your admin powers being used without your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking to do this?

Do you wish to have a program you're creating bypass UAC? If so, you should rewrite your program to require less elevated privileges.

If you're looking to do this so that you're not bothered with UAC, you can turn it off in the control panel. Search "UAC".

Finally, if you want UAC but you want to be able to quickly enter your credentials I would suggest AutoHotkey. That program has a record function which you could use to create a macro that would fill in your credentials in the UAC window every time you press the designated hotkey.

Comment: John, are you sure the last approach would work? If the OP uses UAC with the greyed screen, no other program should have access to the input box, that's the whole point of this feature.

Comment: Is there a way, like putting keys to the keyboard buffer or emulating keyboard presses?

Comment: The idea is to make it easier to do automation for network administrator functions, like update MSI without going to each PC and PC and PC...

Comment: I wasn't aware of the limitation the grayed out screen imposes (probably because I hate UAC =P ) you'd have to try AutoHotkey and see if it works. But wouldn't the simplest solution just be to log in as the admin, run your updates, and reboot into the regular user account? I assume these are a bunch of fat clients? How many are there?

Comment: UAC Does not allow AutoHotkey to enter user and password using a hotkey.