# How to press TAB button in Windows Security pop-up

Tags: c#, selenium, popupwindow

I'm trying to handle Internet Explorer Windows Security pop-up using OpenQA.Selenium.IAlert by sending userName and password. I need to press TAB and Enter buttons in this windows. Key {TAB} sends text instead of button press. Is there any methods to simulate button press using C# for this window?

Code:

```
    var securityWindow = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    securityWindow.SendKeys("username");
    securityWindow.SendKeys("{TAB}");
    securityWindow.SendKeys("Password");
    securityWindow.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
```

[Windows Security window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF9nU.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378135/programatically-auto-fill-uac-details

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the keys class.

```
securityWindow.SendKeys(Keys.Tab);
securityWindow.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: void SendKeys(string keysToSend)
    Member of OpenQA.Selenium.IAlert
takes string

Comment: @PavelGalich Did you try converting the key to an string `Convert.ToString(Keys.Tab)`

Comment: It wil send string "Tab" to textbox. OpenQA.Selenium.IAlert SendKeys it is not System.Windows.Forms SendKeys. It is different methods.